# cookies with expires not getting set in IE9

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a simple controller method whose single task is to set cookies.

```
def consume
    cookies.signed[:luke_luke] = {:value => 'luke'}
    cookies.signed[:remembertoken] = {
      :value => "user",
      :expires => 1.hour.from_now
    }
    render :text => "Failure"
end
```

When I load IE 9, and type document.cookie into the console, I am only getting back the value for luke_luke, but not remember token. When I remove the expiration on remember token, all is well. What gives?

Using Rails 3.2.13

Comment: confirmed for IE 8 as well.

Answer (score 1):

IE <= 9 discards cookies with explicit expirations less than 1.day.from_now

A possible workaround would be to set a separate timestamped cookie, say :remembertoken_expires, at the same time you set :remembertoken, check that timestamp against Time.now, and explicitly delete the cookies if Time.now > :remembertoken_expires.

Comment: got it to work by increasing expiration to 3.hours.from_now - anything under that wouldn't set.